# Regexp для img (jpg, jpeg, png)

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение для проверки url картинки, т.е. что бы:

1) url начинался на https (хотя я не уверена, нужно ли это)

2) заканчивался на jpg, jpeg, png

Если я что-то пропустила, то подскажите, пожалуйста.

Я пыталась использовать вот что:

```
if (preg_match('http(s ?):)|([/|.|\w | \s])*\.(?:jpg | jpeg | png', $_POST['url']))
```

Но что-то идет нет так.

Comment: скобки и пробелы идут не так. parse_url не хотите использовать? обязательно регулярки?

Comment: @Біпач вроде так, проверьте `'~https?://[\S.]+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)\b~'`

Comment: @teran, а, я и не слышала о нем. но что-то не пойму как им пользоваться. просто проверять тот массив, который он возвращает?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MdjcE8/1

Comment: @Эдуард, нет, и это не работает

Comment: @Біпач я только что подправил шаблон - должен отработать.

Comment: @splash58, ооо, спасибо вам огромное С: какой полезный сайт

Comment: @Эдуард, да, работает. Спасибо, а то  я совсем не разбираюсь в этих регулярках С:

Comment: На всякий случай, упомяну, что расширение - просто часть имени файла и никак не помогает при определении содержимого файла.

Comment: @svgrafov, как так? Разве у фала с окончанием jpg | jpeg | png содержимое не может быть только картинкой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *" Спасибо, а то я совсем не разбираюсь в этих регулярках "*

Самое время начинать. Давайте разберём regex-шаблон конкретно для вашей задачи *(я не буду заключать его в апострофы, т.к. как записываются строки в PHP вам уже известно)*:

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
```

Шаблон состоит из нескольких частей, он должен начинаться и заканчиваться любым не буквенно-числовым символом *(это ограничители шаблона)*. В нашем примере в роли ограничителей выступает пара тильд **~**...**~**

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
^                              ^
```

Следующий после открывающего ограничителя символ **^** *(так называемая "крышка")* сообщает о том, что эта позиция подстроки должна соответствовать началу строки *(т.е., слева от "крышки" не должно быть никаких символов)*

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
 ^
```

Далее идут пять букв **https**, означающих *сами себя*, и квантификатор **?**, действие которого относится к предшествующему его символу **s**. Квантификатор **?** служит для ограничения символов (в данном случае, его действие распространяется на букву *s*), и говорит о том, что символ *s* может находиться в указанной позиции 0 или 1 раз *(иначе говоря, символ s не обязателен, подстрока 'http' без 's' так же будет соответствовать шаблону)*

Следующие три символа подстроки **://** означают сами себя, и в объяснении не нуждаются.

Нам известно, что валидные URL-адреса не могут содержать пробелов - возьмём это за основу, и после двойных слешей запишем метасимвол **\S**, означающий любой символ, кроме пробела *(не пробел)*

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
           ^^
```

Следующий за ним квантификатор **+** *(плюс)* говорит о том, что *не пробел* в текущей позиции является обязательным, и может встречаться в подстроке 1 или более раз

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
             ^
```

После "обязательного" квантификатора + записана группа подстрок, заключённых в не сохраняющие скобки **(?:**...**)**

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
              ^^^            ^
```

Не сохраняющие скобки отличаются от обычных тем, что совпавший внутри них текст не захватывается механизмом регулярных выражений, и не может быть использован, как ссылка на эту группу *(подмаску)*. Не сохраняющие скобки служат для ограничения группы альтернативного выбора *(ИЛИ "|")*

```
(?:jpg|jpeg|png)
      ^    ^
```

Ну и последний метасимвол - **$** *(знак доллара)* служит для ограничения шаблона, и обозначает конец подстроки. Иначе говоря, после него не должно быть никаких символов, кроме символа конца строки

```
~^https?://\S+(?:jpg|jpeg|png)$~
                              ^
```

Итак, этот шаблон можно прочитать так: строка соответствует шаблону, если:

1. она начинается с подстроки **http**
2. за которой следует не обязательный литерал **s**
3. после которого записаны три символа **://**
4. после которых записан один или более не пробельных символов **\S**
5. после которых строка должна закончиться одним из расширений: **jpg**
   или **jpeg** или **png**

Comment: Ухты, спасибо Вам. Теперь хоть буду знать что пишу) На самом деле я думала что там всё намного страшнее

Comment: @Біпач это только на первый взгляд так может показаться, но когда начинаешь изучать регулярки, то многое там оказывается интуитивно понятным. Есть очень хорошая книга: "Регулярные выражения", автор Джеффри Фридл.

Answer (score 0):

можно и упростить ^https?:\S+.(?:jpe?g|png)$